# Is this explanation of a Non-Inferiority Margin Correct?

Tags: confidence-interval, binomial-distribution, biostatistics, clinical-trials, non-inferiority

I'm relatively new to the field of biostats and was reading up on Non-Inferiority Trials and Margins and came across this explanation which is tripping me off a bit.

"For example, the oral Tebipenem HBr study cited above set a Non-Inferiority Margin of -12.5% for the primary endpoint of overall response rate. This means in a head-to-head trial, as long as the 95% Confidence Interval for the response rate with tebipenem was not lower than 87.5% of what was seen with intravenous ertapenem , the oral drug would have been deemed non-inferior"

What is this 87.5% number? I'm assuming he took 100 - 12.5 = 87.5% but what does that have to do with the Non-inferiority margin?

Here is the link to the actual study: https://www.nejm.org/doi/10.1056/NEJMoa2105462

Say for example the intravenous ertapem response rate is 50%. Then 87.5% of 50 is 43.75. Does that mean to pass non inferiority the new drugs response rate 95% confidence interval has to be at the very least above 43.75%? In which case the NON-Inferiority Margin would be 43.75-50=-6.25% and not -12.5 ??

Alternatively say for example IV ertapem has a 25% Response rate. A -12.5% Non Inferiority Margin would mean the new drug can only go as low 12.5%. But 12.5% of 25% is 50% not 87.5%

The only way I can understand it is that he's saying that at any given moment the absolute risk difference from the 95% CI should never be lower than -12.5% (but that doesn't necessarily mean it's an 87.5% Response Rate of IV ertapem. Look at my 2nd example above)

Comment: Could you please edit the question to provide a link to the quote (or even better to the cited "oral Tebipenem HBr study")? Expressions of "percentage differences" can mean either percentage differences or percentage-_point_ differences, which as you note can be quite different and lead to confusion.  Without knowing the original reference, it's hard to say what the original authors intended or whether they were interpreted correctly in the quote you included in the question. Then an answer can focus on the more important statistical issue of a non-inferiority margin.

Comment: @EdM Here is the link to the actual study the author was referring to: nejm.org/doi/10.1056/NEJMoa2105462 Most of the examples I have seen online for Non-Inferiority either use an Absolute Risk Difference(Percentage Points) or a Relative Risk Ratio. And in this specific case the study is using Percentage Points aswell. Although, your explanation that it could potentially be a Relative Risk Difference that the explanation was using instead of Absolute Risk Difference could be why the author was confusing me(which would mean he's wrong then)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one reason why I dislike percentages: it’s often not clear whether a “percent difference” is a difference in percentage *points* between treatment $t$ and control $c$ ($100*(p_t - p_c)$, where $p$ is a probability) or a percentage difference from the control success rate ($100*(p_t-p_c)/ p_c$).

As I read the original NEJM paper, the authors (in consultation with the FDA) apparently adjusted the design for a noninferiority margin of 12.5 percentage *points*, which is *not* how the quote in the second paragraph of your question interpreted it. That’s a big difference in interpretation when the overall response rate to the control drug is only about 60%, as in the NEJM report. Supporting my interpretation, the [FDA guidance](https://www.fda.gov/media/78504/download) notes on page  9 that “an absolute difference in effect” is typically the choice of margin for antibiotic trials like that reported in the NEJM paper.

For learning about issues in noninferiority trials, that FDA guidance isn’t a bad place to start. With respect to different types of “percent differences,” for example, there’s a simple explanation starting on page 24. Figure 3 nicely illustrates the interpretation of results from noninferiority trials. Much of the document focuses on the difficulties in choosing a noninferiority margin for study design.

Comment: So we can come to an agreement that the author who said 87.5% is wrong.

Comment: @user387320 you and I agree on that, at least. Perhaps the author you quote had some additional information on which to base the statement, but that seems unlikely and is inconsistent with the specific statements of percentage-point differences through most of the NEJM paper.

Answer (score 1):

If the text does not provide much information, i would check how its analysis was conducted, e.g. here "The primary analysis was the comparison of the overall response at the test-of-cure visit in the microbiologic intention-to-treat population. The 95% confidence interval for the weighted difference between treatment groups was calculated with the use of the Cochran–Mantel–Haenszel weighted Miettinen and Nurminen method (stratified according to age at the time of informed consent and baseline diagnosis)." So the difference between two proportions was calculated, thus this margin is an absolute margin, i.e. if the difference > -0.125 then NI was demonstrated.
If the analysis is a risk ratio, then would be a relative margin, i.e. $p_{test}/p_{control}>0.875 $.